# Difference between an variable set to nil and 0

Tags: objective-c, null

```
if (myFloat == nil){
    \\Do Method
}
```

In the above situation, the method will run only if `myFloat` is `nil`.  Will it also run if `myFloat` was set to `0`?

Comment: Is myFloat an actual `float` type? If so, you shouldn't ever be setting/comparing it to `nil`, which is only valid for object references. It's an apples-to-oranges comparison, even though in this specific case it might work, as nil and zero are essentially the same thing when the code is compiled.

Comment: Is there a nil equivalent for types like float?

Comment: @G P Burdell: No, there isn't because `float` is not a pointer type.  Well, actually, I guess you could use NaN for floating point values. http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nil  should only be used with pointers. It says that the pointer has not been set to a value.

Floats and other C types just have a value. (Strictly floats and double possibly can have values like NaN but this is more difficult to manage)

In Objective C you can wrap a float in the class NSNumber. An object of this class is referenced by a pointer so a variable of type NSNumber* can be nil.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Highlighing words is not a valid edit see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155904/highlighting-technical-words/155906#155906

Answer (score 0):

Well, nil is technically 0. However, some of this depends on what type of variable myFloat is. If myFloat is a C float, you can't depend on it being exactly 0. You really should be using nil on id types.

Comment: But what should I use for primitive types like float?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. If you have a pointer to a float, you can compare to 0. However, you should look at how floating point numbers are represented in a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into my answer, see [this table from NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nil/) for a refresher on the meanings of the family of null-like symbols:

| Symbol | Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `NULL` | `(void *)0` | literal null value for C pointers |
| `nil` | `(id)0` | literal null value for Obj-C objects |
| `Nil` | `(Class)0` | literal null value for Obj-C classes |
| `NSNull` | `[NSNull null]` | singleton object used to represent null |

As the value column above shows, all but `NSNull` have 0 as their underlying value.

I ran a few test cases related to nil-checking and zero-checking.

Key:

- ✅ condition was satisfied, so the log printed
- ❌ condition was not satisfied, so the log didn't print

```objectivec
NSNumber* nilNSNumber = nil;
if(nilNSNumber == nil){
    NSLog(@"nilNSNumber == nil"); // ✅
}
if(nilNSNumber == 0){
    NSLog(@"nilNSNumber == 0"); // ✅
}

NSNumber* zeroNSNumberA = 0;
if(zeroNSNumberA == nil){
    NSLog(@"zeroNSNumberA == nil"); // ✅
}

NSNumber* zeroNSNumberB = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
if(zeroNSNumberB == nil){
    NSLog(@"zeroNSNumberB == nil"); // ❌
}
if(zeroNSNumberB == 0){
    NSLog(@"zeroNSNumberB == 0"); // ❌
}

NSObject* objectUninitialised = [NSObject alloc];
if(objectUninitialised == nil){
    NSLog(@"objectUninitialised == nil"); // ❌
}
if(objectUninitialised == 0){
    NSLog(@"objectUninitialised == 0"); // ❌
}

NSObject* objectInitialised = [objectUninitialised init];
if(objectInitialised == nil){
    NSLog(@"objectInitialised == nil"); // ❌
}
if(objectUninitialised == 0){
    NSLog(@"objectInitialised == 0"); // ❌
}

if([NSNull null] == 0){
    NSLog(@"NSNull == 0"); // ❌
}
if([NSNull null] == nil){
    NSLog(@"NSNull == nil"); // ❌
}
```